# JavaFX TabPane width and Button width don´t match

Tags: button, javafx, tabs, width, pane

While I was trying to use the `TabPane` container in JavaFX I noticed, that if I give the *Tabs* in the `TabPane` a specific width and another element e.g. a `Button` the exact same width, they show up on the screen with different sizes.

Here is an example: [As you can see in this image, the Button is smaller than the width of the tap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/equ51.png)

Here is the Code I for this specific image:

```
package stackOverflow;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Tab;
import javafx.scene.control.TabPane;
import javafx.scene.control.TabPane.TabClosingPolicy;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class TabPaneMystery extends Application {

public static void main(String[] args){

    launch(args);

}

@Override
public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {

    StackPane stackPane = new StackPane();
    Scene scene = new Scene(stackPane, 600, 400);

    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.show();

    TabPane tabPane = new TabPane();
    stackPane.getChildren().add(tabPane);
    Tab tab1 = new Tab();

    tabPane.setTabMaxWidth(160);        //The width of the tab is '160'
    tabPane.setTabMinWidth(160);
    tabPane.setTabClosingPolicy(TabClosingPolicy.UNAVAILABLE);

    tab1.setText("Tab");
    tabPane.getTabs().add(tab1);

    Button b = new Button();
    b.setText("Button");
    b.setPrefWidth(160);                //The width of the button is '160'
    b.setTranslateX(6);

    tab1.setContent(b);

}

}
```

in Line 33 and 34 *(where the first comment is)* I set the width of the tapPane to be `160` and in Line 42 *(where the second comment is)* I set the exact same width
This results in the shown image.

*My question is:*
Have I made an obvious mistake or is it some kind of bug or does the compiler interpret the width for every node somewhat different?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect you're seeing some padding in the `Tab`.  The actual width of the `Tab` comes out to `170`. You can confirm this by changing the width of the `Tab` to `150`; it will then be the exact same size as the `Button`:

[image: screenshot1]

You could also use CSS to remove the padding:

```
tab1.setStyle("-fx-padding: 0");
```

Although, as you can see below, it isn't an exact match and there may be other CSS properties to look into. Hope this gets you closer to your goal, though:

[image: screenshot2]

Comment: `Button` might also have some padding. What happens if you remove it?

Comment: @Slaw - Removing the padding from the `Button` reduces the height, but not the width. Interesting.

Comment: A bit more interesting when you know that in modena.css file, there is padding on all sides by default : `.button... {....; -fx-padding: 0.333333em 0.666667em 0.333333em 0.666667em; ...}`.